# Can I use 220V inverter as 12V power supply?

Tags: ac, battery-charging, inverter

I have a pure sine wave inverter, it charges a 12V battery and converts 12V from battery to 220V during a power cut. 
Since it can output 12V to charge the battery at quite a high current I was wondering if I could use it as a 12V power supply.
I connected the 12V output to a multimeter and it seems to be jumping from 6.xx volts to 13.xx. I reckon it automatically selects 6V or 12V battery.
So is there any way I could bypass this jumping from one voltage to another to use it as a power supply?

Comment: You need to add a lot more information to this question. First of all, which IC are you using? Link the datasheet. Second, how are you planning on using it? What are the specs of the system you want to use it with?

Comment: I am really sorry, if I had any information about it I would have posted it, but I could not find anything.

Comment: If you can't find any information on the IC, then **DON'T USE IT** simple as that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have sounds like an UPS (uninterruptible power supply).

The UPS have a charge controller that will detect the state of charge of the battery, so if no battery is connected and only some circuit, it won't work as the charge controller won't understand what is going on.

Although, you can connect a battery to it and then use it as a 12V power supply with the battery connected and this should work as the battery will keep a constant 12V (about) to the charge controller.

Comment: One thing to note is OP mentioned int he comments that they cannot find any information about the device. Which Is why I said to not use it

Comment: @MCG Well, presumably it does its job. Why do you think it is an IC? It sounds like a complete consumer device.

Comment: @user253751 I'm a bit confused with your comment. I said it sounds like a UPS, not an IC